# How do I edit the text attribute in SVG created rectangles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, text, edit

I am drawing the svg which has four rectangles, and each rectangle has specific text(label). I have a requirement to be able to edit the text and it should take the label defined by user. I tried few things like using input box and also contenteditable true attribute for the text, but nothing seems to be working for me. I have shared the part of my code and also jsfiddle link.

```
const drawSvg= svg.append("g")
. append("rect")
.attr("id", "myRect")
. style("fill", function (d) {color});
g.selectAll("g"). append("text").attr("id", "myText")
.text (function (d) {return label;});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ypvoxf6h/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
Array.from(document.querySelector('.svg').querySelectorAll('text')).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    const rect_text = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.value = evt.target.innerHTML;
    input.onkeyup = function(e) {
      if (["Enter", "Escape"].includes(e.key)) {
        this.blur();
        return;
      }
      evt.target.innerHTML = this.value;
    };
    input.onblur = function(e) {
      input.remove();
    };
    input.style.left = rect_text.left + 'px';
    input.style.top = rect_text.top + 'px';
    input.style.width = 2 + 'ch';
    input.style.height = rect_text.height + 'px';
    document.querySelector('.svg').append(input);
    input.focus();
  });
});
```

```css
.svg input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg">
  <svg id="mySVG" viewBox="0 0 4 2" width="400px">
        <g dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size=".73">
            <rect x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1.2" style="fill: rgb(255, 46, 0);"/>
            <text class="text1" x="0.2" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">0</text>
            <rect x="1" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(0, 184, 0);"/>
            <text class="text2" x="1.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">1</text>
            <rect x="2" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(0, 25, 255);"/>
            <text class="text3" x="2.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">2</text>
            <rect x="3" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(179, 179, 179);"/>
            <text class="text4" x="3.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">3</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

not same as your jsfiddle example, but nicer you edit "almost" onplace

Comment: I actually facing one issue when I try same on my code, issue is with input box. When I focus on the input box, I see whole background as black color for the input. Have also posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75081173/input-box-in side-the-svg-shows-black-color-on-focus

Comment: Also, in my case I am not able to add input inside SVG without using foreignObject but I wonder how it works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is to change the inner text, you can put a class in each text, select it by class, change the inner text.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('#mySVG').querySelector('.text1').innerHTML = 'A';
```

```html
<svg id="mySVG" viewBox="0 0 4 2" width="400px">
    <g dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size=".73">
        <rect x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1.2" style="fill: rgb(255, 46, 0);"/>
        <text class="text1" x="0.2" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">0</text>
        <rect x="1" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(0, 184, 0);"/>
        <text class="text2" x="1.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">1</text>
        <rect x="2" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(0, 25, 255);"/>
        <text class="text3" x="2.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">2</text>
        <rect x="3" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(179, 179, 179);"/>
        <text class="text4" x="3.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">3</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The way I want it to be like it should be changed like input box text or kind of editable by the user, the user must be able to type label for it

Answer (score 0):

yes you had everything to do that, just to add the input change...

```js
document.querySelector('#text1').addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
  document.querySelector('#mySVG').querySelector('.' + evt.target.id).innerHTML = evt.target.value;
})
```

```html
<svg id="mySVG" viewBox="0 0 4 2" width="400px">
    <g dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size=".73">
        <rect x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1.2" style="fill: rgb(255, 46, 0);"/>
        <text class="text1" x="0.2" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">0</text>
        <rect x="1" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(0, 184, 0);"/>
        <text class="text2" x="1.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">1</text>
        <rect x="2" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(0, 25, 255);"/>
        <text class="text3" x="2.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">2</text>
        <rect x="3" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(179, 179, 179);"/>
        <text class="text4" x="3.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">3</text>
    </g>
</svg>

<label for="text1">text 1
<input id="text1" value="0"></label>
```

Done for text1... you can copy & paste for the others

Comment: I tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/n3wzy98c/1/ but it does not allow me to edit text for example from "0" to "A"

Comment: ?? It's working in browser! It's working here in snippet! It's working in your jsfiddle! You enter "A" in the input, it changes the 0 to A

Comment: I wanted something like this https://jsfiddle.net/5m6zjexd/, if you see in this example, it allows us to edit at that particular place and update the text