# Input box inside the SVG shows black color on focus

Tags: javascript, svg, input, text

I am drawing the svg which has three rectangles, and each rectangle has specific text(label). I have a requirement to be able to edit the text and it should take the label defined by user.
I tried few things like using input box and also contenteditable true attribute for the text, to edit the SVG text. Unfortunately, contenteditable is not working and using input box works partially. The issue with input box is that when i focus on the input, I see black color as shown in snapshot below and not sure from where it is taking. Since I am getting issue when the input box is focused, I am not able to debug as well, since when I click inspect element, the focus gets loose and there won't be any black color to debug. I am not sure if the black color is related to some font issue or something else, tried altering font but nothing worked.
I have shared the part of my code.

```
const drawSvg= svg.append("g")
. append("rect")
.attr("id", "myRect")
. style("fill", function (d) {color});
g.selectAll("g"). append("text").attr("id", "myText").on("click", textClick)
.text (function (d) {return label;});
g.selectAll("g").append("foreignObject")

function textClick(evt) {
let originalText = evt.target.innerHTML
const input = document.createElement("input");
input.value = originalText;
input.onkeyup = function(e) {
evt.target.innerHTML = input.value;
};
input.onfocus = function(e) { 
evt.target.innerHTML = input.value;
};
input.onblur = function(e) {
input.remove();
};
input.style.fontSize = "1.25em"
input.style.padding = "0"
input.style.border = "none"
input.style.height = "1px"
input.style.width = "4px"
const myCells = document.querySelectorAll('.myForeignObject');
for (let i=0; i < myCells.length; i++) {
myCells[i].appendChild(input)
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged react?

Comment: I have other function written in react in my code, but I will remove it if it is not relevant here

Comment: Does the foreignObject you are appending the input to have height, width, x and y attributes ?

Comment: Yes, I have given all the necessary attributes to the foreignObject. Since I am getting issue when the input box is focused, I am not able to debug as well, since when I click inspect element, the focus gets loose and there won't be any black color to debug